# Is there a way to add your drive to WSL ubuntu home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently got WSL working with ubuntu. I got code . working, zsh, added in homebrew, and I figured out that the drive is in the mnt folder. I was wondering if there is a way to add your hard drive into the ubuntu home folder ~?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In your bash you can set an alias to your c drive. I have mine set like this `wsl alias="cd ../../../mnt/c/wsl_ubuntu"`

Then you can do it where on terminal start it will load you in there like this
`cd ../../../mnt/c/wsl_ubuntu`

However, it is super slow, so I wouldn't recommend doing that. I wish you could use it with your c drive. It's kind of sad how apple or ubuntu can have it all together but not yet in windows :(.